# Shell: Get first IP in the given network

Tags: shell, networking, ip, gateway

I have one IP say `192.168.20.1/23`. I want to get the gateway from this IP, which I know would be the first IP in given network.

How can I achieve this through the shell script? The network and CIDR are keep going to change.

Comment: The IP you have provided is the destination IP address?

Comment: check http://serverfault.com/questions/690930/first-and-last-ip-address-of-the-network-192-168-176-0-23-subnet-23

Comment: @Inian actually it's local IP. I want to fetch the gateway from this.

Comment: @PS. I want to achieve this through the shell script.

Comment: @GaneshSatpute: Are there any entries except `0.0.0.0` from the output of `route -n` command?

Comment: @Inian there are few entries. What I want to achieve is, I have some eth somebody else has assigned an IP to it. Now, I have figured out IP and netmask using `ip` command. I want to add one default route to the machine. Problem is I need to calculate the gateway, and I really can't hardcode it.